# Implementing Detachable Panel in UWP App

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-10-universal

I have an [`Image`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image) in a grid where I display some custom content by setting the Image's source to a [`WritableBitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap) and updating the bitmap. What I want to do is to implement a "detach" button that will put my Image on a separate window allowing the user to move it to a different screen, resize it etc. independent of my main app window. If the new window is closed, I would like to bring it back to its original spot. While the Image is on the new window, I want to continuously update it with new content via updating source bitmap (as it would have been before it was detached).

I initially thought I would be able to create a new window and "move" my Image control there by first removing it from its original parent then adding it as a child to a layout in the new window. I used the code below:

```
CoreApplicationView^ newCoreView = CoreApplication::CreateNewView();
int mainViewId = Windows::UI::ViewManagement::ApplicationView::GetApplicationViewIdForWindow(
    CoreApplication::MainView->CoreWindow);

uint indexOfObjectToDetach = -1;
bool found = originalGrid->Children->IndexOf(imageToMove, &indexOfObjectToDetach);
if(found)
{
    myGrid->Children->RemoveAt(indexOfObjectToDetach);
}

DispatchedHandler^ dispatchHandler = ref new DispatchedHandler([this, mainViewId]()
{
    newView_ = Windows::UI::ViewManagement::ApplicationView::GetForCurrentView();
    Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::StackPanel^ newWindowGrid = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::StackPanel();
    Window::Current->Content = newWindowGrid;
    Window::Current->Activate();

    newWindowGrid->Children->Append(imageToMove); // Add to new parent
});

create_task(newCoreView->Dispatcher->RunAsync(Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, dispatchHandler)).then([this, mainViewId]()
{
    auto a = newView_->Id;
    create_task(ApplicationViewSwitcher::TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(a, ViewSizePreference::Default, mainViewId, ViewSizePreference::Default));
});
```

However in the line where I add the Image to its new parent, I get an `Interface was marshalled for a different thread` error. Upon more reading, this is due to the fact that each new window is in its own thread and I'm moving an object to another thread.

I am new to UWP and I am not sure how to approach implementing this UI behavior. How do I access/transfer my state in one view to another ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is indeed the fact that each application view in UWP has its own thread and its own UI dispatcher. When you create a control, it is tied to the UI thread it was created on, hence you cannot place it onto another application view.

The solution is to create the new `Image` next to the `StackPanel` within the new view's UI thread. I don't really use C++, but in C# I would implement it as follows:

```
await newCoreView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
        Image image = new Image();
        panel.Children.Add( panel );
        image.Source = ...; //your source
        Window.Current.Content = frame;
        Window.Current.Activate();
        newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
    });
```

To further clarify - you can safely "transfer" normal data types into other view, the problem is mainly with the UI-tied types like controls, pages, etc.